# How to concat columns in Sequelize with SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, express, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize for a express project I'm working on.
In one query I want to retrieve a concatenated result of two columns.

Like:

```
SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name AS full_name FROM table
```

I tried the following syntax and got an error

```
router.get('/persons', function(req, res, next) {
  models.Person.findAll({
    attributes: [models.sequelize.fn('CONCAT', 'first_name', 'last_name')]
  })
    .then(function(persons) {
      res.send(persons);
    });
});
```

The error message:

```
SELECT CONCAT('first_name', 'last_name') FROM `Persons` AS `Person`;
Possibly unhandled SequelizeDatabaseError: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such function: CONCAT
```

Comment: Have you tried using `literal`? I don't have Sequelize set up anywhere so I can't check but maybe something like `models.sequelize.literal("first_name || ' ' || last_name")` would work.

Comment: Thank you! it's working now (:

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used `models.sequelize.literal`, that creates a object representing a literal,
inside nested array to give it an alias.

#### The result:

```
router.get('/persons', function(req, res, next) {
  models.Person.findAll({
    attributes: [models.sequelize.literal("first_name || ' ' || last_name"), 'full_name']
  })
    .then(function(persons) {
      res.send(persons);
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I concat string with column value of attributes?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issues, I solve like this

```
const { fn, col } = Person.sequelize;

const res = Person.findAll({
   attributes: [ [fn('concat', col('first_name'), ' ', col('last_name')), "FullName"], ...OthersColumns ]
})
```

I hope help you or others